# How to remove custom console component in edit page?

Tags: custom-console-components

I have added a custom console component in the right side bar. But on the record creating page itself , i am able to see this. Please tell me how to remove it

Screenshot :[image]

Comment: is it possible to take a screenshot where you want to remove ?

Comment: I am not able to add any screenshot in comment

Comment: You may edit your question and add a screenshot ?

Comment: Ya its done @erkan!!

Comment: Since the create page and edit page in the Salesforce is the same program, I don't think it is possible to remove component from "create" page as long as you need to keep it in the "edit" page. In other words, if you remove the component away from create page, then you can not see it in the edit page.

Comment: You can figure out what is going on in the main area of the page "ie your creating a record" and then adjust your call comments box appropriately. So rather than removing it you could do a search on similar leads or something. Then once saved your call comments appear.

Comment: can you be little bit specific.. Sorry i am not able to get you @francis

Comment: Salesforce has the Salesforce console integration toolkit. With this there are a load of Javascript methods to determine eg what tabs are in them what the urls are for each of the tabs etc (eg: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm). What you can do from your "Add comment" visualforce is use these javascript methods to determine what is in the left frame. Then depending on whats there either show you "Add Comments" functionality or not.

Answer (score 0):

Cray Kao's comment is correct. The console determines which sidebars to use at the time the tab is created based on the type of tab it is. So when you create a new Lead, it determines which page layout is associated with the record type (if any) of the Lead and generates all the sidebars at that time. There isn't a declarative way to avoid this sidebar from showing up on the creation page without removing it entirely.

You could use the Console Toolkit to hide it, however. It would still be there if a user wanted to make it appear manually, but it would be hidden by default. One way that comes to mind is creating a custom console component and using an event listener for the OPEN_TAB event, then hiding sidebars when that event happens for the pages you want. It could look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var listenerFunction = function(result) { 
    //if for some reason we don't get a return value
    if(!result) { return; } 
    //Check if the new tab is a Lead, then close the right sidebar
    if(result.objectId.substring(0,3) == '00Q') { 
        sforce.console.setSidebarVisible( false, result.id, "sforce.console.Region.RIGHT");
    }
} 

sforce.console.addEventListener( "sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.OPEN_TAB", listenerFunction);
```

The toolkit documentation can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_events.htm)